# I want to create a functionality in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, database, foreach

I want to create a functionality on Laravel that would check the rows of a database table for existence. After checking, depending on the results of the check, it should delete, add new columns or skip them.

```
foreach($this->category_product as $k => $item) {
        $category_product = CategoryProduct::where([['category_id', $this->category_id],['product_id', $k]])->firstOr(function () {
                $category_product = CategoryProduct::create([
                        'category_id' => $this->category_id,
                        'product_id' => $k
                ]);
        });
}
```

Here's what I have so far. How to remove rows that do not exist in a query?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you right, as the question isn't clear enough, but here is a way to delete the rows if they exist:

Note: you were missing `use ($k)`

```php
foreach ($this->category_product as $k => $item) {
    $category_product = CategoryProduct::where([
        ['category_id', $this->category_id],
        ['product_id', $k]
    ])->firstOr(function () use ($k) {
        // Delete if it exists.
        CategoryProduct::where([
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,
            'product_id' => $k
        ])->delete();

        // Create if it doesn't exist.
        $category_product = CategoryProduct::create([
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,
            'product_id' => $k
        ]);

    });
}
```